# What can cause 5 sec delay during saving file in VIM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

What can cause an issue when I am saving a file in rails application folder freezing for about 5 seconds? How to investigate this issue?

**VIMRC**: https://gist.github.com/4632cbcfc655899c934f

Comment: I installed VIM trough homebrew and I have version `7.4.52`

Comment: Have you verified that there is no similar problem A) with other editors and B) with copying files in that directory?

Comment: Nano writes immediately. Coping works fast too.

Comment: Hmm, clear version of VIM save files fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like some autocommand running, whenever you save a file. According to your .vimrc you have one `BufWritePost` autocommand, so could it be, that it is causing your delay?

Try running `:noa :w` to make sure, no autocommand kicks in, when saving a file. So you can at least eliminate BufWrite autocommands. See also the [faq](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5) on how to debug some unwanted behaviour with your Vim.